# How can I remove the last 2 words in a string?

Tags: java

I have got a string containing an address and I want to remove the post code which is the last 2 words.

eg `21 Lane Street London W10 2GH`

I want 'W10 2GH' removed

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Replace the pattern `\s*\w+\s+\w+$` with an empty String:

```
String s = "21 Lane Street London W10 2GH";
System.out.println(s.replaceFirst("\\s*\\w+\\s+\\w+$", ""));
```

produces:

```
21 Lane Street London
```

A short explanation:

```
\s*  # zero or more white space chars
\w+  # one or more alpha-nums (or underscore), specifically: [a-zA-Z0-9_]
\s+  # one or more white space chars
\w+  # one or more alpha-nums (or underscore)
$    # the end of the input
```

Comment: Can you explain to me what that regrex is doing exactly please. thanks

Comment: just see java.util.regex.Pattern

Comment: @Dave: added a short explanation.

Comment: You probably want to restrict this a bit more -- use \w\w\w or \w{3}.  Otherwise, it will match things like '21 Lane Street London' and convert to '21 Lane'.  Or even '\w\d\d\s+\d\w\w'.

Comment: @Charlie, good point. Although I will leave my answer for what it is and leave the fine-tuning to the OP.

Answer (score 1):

Lots of ways.  The easiest in this situation is just use <strike>`rindex()`</strike> `lastIndexOf()` to find the blanks.

It might be a bit safer and stronger to use a regular expression to search for actual post codes.

Comment: You have a reference for `rindex()` ?

Comment: By rindex() I think Charlie meant lastIndexOf, here: http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#lastIndexOf(java.lang.String) (all the three overloads may be useful)